# Laravel Sail - TenancyForLaravel Package Local Domains

Tags: laravel

I've installed laravel from scratch with Sail.
And installed Tenancy for Laravel step by step: https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/quickstart

My laravel project is working with: http://localhost
But not working http://foo.localhost or http://bar.localhost.

My central domains:

```
'central_domains' => [
    '127.0.0.1',
    'localhost',
],
```

My RouteServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * Typically, users are redirected here after authentication.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = '/home';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, and other route configuration.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            $this->mapApiRoutes();
            $this->mapWebRoutes();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Configure the rate limiters for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureRateLimiting()
    {
        RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(60)->by($request->user()?->id ?: $request->ip());
        });
    }
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        foreach ($this->centralDomains() as $domain) {
            Route::middleware('web')
                ->domain($domain)
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
        }
    }

    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        foreach ($this->centralDomains() as $domain) {
            Route::prefix('api')
                ->domain($domain)
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
        }
    }

    protected function centralDomains(): array
    {
        return config('tenancy.central_domains');
    }
}
```

Whats wrong with the configuration.
Why my subdomains are not working?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check **Domain Table** in your main database. Is there any entry regarding your domain like foo.localhost etc.